# Как получить все параметры из базы sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

Мне нужно перед внесением в базу данных проверить все значения и если есть точное совпадение, то получить id этой строчки, если нет, то получить в ответ 0

Написал такой скрипт:

```
def chek_db(a):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
    res = conn.execute("SELECT q_id, q_title FROM q_main WHERE q_title LIKE" + '\'' + a + '\'')
    res1 = len(res.fetchall())

    if res1 == 0:
        result = 0
    else: result = 1

    return (result)
```

Пытался модернизировать, чтобы он в ответ отдавал q_id, но ничего не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Раз у Вас точное соответствие, то зачем Вам оператор `like`? Он используется при поиске по шаблонам
2. Вы не длину результат получайте, а сам результат.
3. Тут более подошла бы функция `fetchone()`, так как ожидается одна или ни одной строки ответа, но я оставил как есть

---

Вот, что получилось в итоге:

```
def chek_db(a):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
    res = conn.execute("SELECT q_id FROM q_main WHERE q_title='" + str(a) + "'")
    res1 = res.fetchall()

    if res1:
        result = res1[0][0] # id находится в первой строке ответа на первом месте 
        return result

    return 0
```

Comment: Мб, лучше добавить пример с binding? Например `conn.execute("SELECT q_id FROM q_main WHERE q_title=?", (a,))`

Comment: Кстати, да. Не был уверен, что модуль поддерживает.  С параметром выглядит гораздо аккуратнее

Comment: Поддерживает: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute . Именованные параметры, кст, тоже

Answer (score -1):

> ничего не получается

Очень познавательно... :-( А что КОНКРЕТНО происходит - можно узнать?

- Программа не компилируется
- При выполнении программы выдаётся какая-то ошибка
- Ошибок не выдаётся, но желаемого результата не видно

Во всяком случае, в тексте SQL запроса у Вас есть ошибка:

```
WHERE q_title LIKE" + '\'' + a + '\''
```

надо вставить пробел между LIKE и параметром:

```
WHERE q_title LIKE " + '\'' + a + '\''
```

Comment: Сергей, по-моему вопрос сформулирован нормально. И код приведен. Совершенно ясно, что не получается и почему. Вот вы один глюк заметили, но с Вашим исправлением все равно результата не будет...

Comment: @SergeyNudnov *Совершенно ясно, что не получается и почему.* - если Вам всё ясно, то зачем Вы задаёте вопрос?

Comment: Это не я задавал этот вопрос. Я давал ответ